# Where is getTable method defined in Virtuemart 2?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

Let's put it simple in the product model we have this notation:

line: 988

```
$mfTable = $this->getTable ('manufacturers');
```

this getTable methods is repeated hundreds of times in product model as well as in other models.

Can someone tell me where it is defined?

Using Komodo as editing tool, it seems to be a Joomla method defined in:
libraries/joomla/application/component/model.php

```
public function getTable($name = '', $prefix = 'Table', $options = array())
{

    if (empty($name))
    {
        $name = $this->getName();
    }

    if ($table = $this->_createTable($name, $prefix, $options))
    {
        return $table;
    }

    JError::raiseError(0, JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_TABLE_NAME_NOT_SUPPORTED', $name));

    return null;
}
```

But if I put any `var_dump` inside or if I comment the content of the function everything seems to work fine as before.

Any support for it?

Comment: I don't know Joomla, but that looks like it would be a sensible parent for a product model. Have a look at what class you refer to first, and then the class you refer to next (in model.php) and see if one extends the other.

Comment: It seems to be the correct path. Make sure that it is actually being called. Perhaps your content is cached.